# Bootstrap 4.4 On Button Click: Changing/Hiding Spinner after Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I've browsed several similar questions about this topic but I don't see one that specifically addressed what I want to happen using the latest Bootstrap version which is 4.4

For starters, please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Yabi/jn92Lyak/4/

What I want is simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Click button > button text: "VERIFY" turns into "Analyzing with spinner" > "Analyzing" fades out > "Checked" appears on the same button.

```
HTML:
<button type="button" id="verifyBtn" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3">VERIFY</button>

CSS:
#verifyBtn {
  margin:30px;
  width:200px;
}

JS:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#verifyBtn').on('click',function(event){
        // disable button
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);

        // add spinner to button for some time
        $(this).html('<span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Analyzing...');  
    });
});
```

Comment: can you clearify what you want exactly you mean verify should change analyzing then after some time analyizing also should change check mark

Comment: I was referring to the text inside the button. By default, it says "VERIFY", but on click.. first, a spinner with the text "Analyzing" appears.. and this should fade out after some seconds.. and then a check or "CHECKED" appears on the same button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change "Analyzing..." to "Checked" after a defined time you can use `setTimeout()` function. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#verifyBtn').on('click',function(event){
        // disable button
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);

        // add spinner to button for some time
        $(this).html('<span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria- 
        hidden="true"></span> Analyzing...');  

        var _self = $(this);

        setTimeout(function(){
            _self.html('CHECKED');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

In this case the word 'CHECKED' will appear inside the button after 3 seconds.

Comment: I actually tried setTimeout or delay() but it doesn't work.. try it in the fiddle above

Comment: Here is the working example in js fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/15hq2t9m/5/`. Maybe it creates a problem when you copy and paste the code from StackOverflow to js fiddle

Comment: Why would you want it to statically reset after 3 seconds instead of resetting after the button's action finishes doing what it was supposed to?

Comment: @IanSmith, the only action for this button is editing HTML content of the clicked button. If we change it to "CHECKED" without `setTimeOut` it will happen almost immediately and we will not see the spinner